# Pinnable taskpane action causing add-in installation problems

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We're trying to install an add-in that makes use of the pinnable taskpane action introduced in version overrides 1.1.

The error reads
"This app can't be installed. The manifest file doesn't conform to the schema definition. The element 'Action' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1' has invalid child element 'SupportsPinning' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1..."

The Exchange server version we're on is Exchange 2016 CU1.

Has anyone encountered this scenario before?

Sample of the manifest below...

```html
<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
        xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">

    <Requirements>
        <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.4">
            <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
        </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>

    <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">

            <DesktopFormFactor>
                <!-- Message read -->
                <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
                    <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                        <Group id="msgreadTabMessage.grp1">
                            <Label resid="groupLabel" />

                            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgreadTabMessage.grp1.btnView">
                                <Label resid="buttonLabel" />
                                <Supertip>
                                    <Title resid="superTipTitle" />
                                    <Description resid="superTip" />
                                </Supertip>
                                <Icon>
                                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon1_16x16" />
                                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon1_32x32" />
                                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon1_80x80" />
                                </Icon>
                                <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                    <SourceLocation resid="taskPaneUrl" />
                                </Action>
                            </Control>
                        </Group>
                    </OfficeTab>
                </ExtensionPoint>
            </DesktopFormFactor>
        </Host>
    </Hosts>                    

    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
        <Hosts>
            <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
                <DesktopFormFactor>
                    <!-- Message read -->
                    <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
                        <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                            <Group id="msgreadTabMessage.grp1">
                                <Label resid="groupLabel" />

                                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgreadTabMessage.grp1.btnView">
                                    <Label resid="buttonLabel" />
                                    <Supertip>
                                        <Title resid="superTipTitle" />
                                        <Description resid="superTip" />
                                    </Supertip>
                                    <Icon>
                                        <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon1_16x16" />
                                        <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon1_32x32" />
                                        <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon1_80x80" />
                                    </Icon>
                                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                        <SourceLocation resid="taskPaneUrl" />
                                        <SupportsPinning>true</SupportsPinning>
                                    </Action>
                                </Control>
                            </Group>
                        </OfficeTab>
                    </ExtensionPoint>
                </DesktopFormFactor>
            </Host>
        </Hosts>
    </VersionOverrides>
</VersionOverrides>
```

Answer (score 2):

SupportsPinning was introduced in Exchange 2016 CU4 and that is why it does not work in CU1 for you.

Comment: So the supportspinning attribute is not backwards compatible?

Will it work in Exchange 2013 at all?

Comment: If your manifest contains "SupportsPinning", you can install it in Exchange 2013, however, it will have no effect on the add-in, which means the add-in won't be pinnable.

Comment: That's great to hear! 

Just curious, why wouldn't a similar situation apply to prior Exchange 2016 CU's, where the attribute will have no effect on the add-in and prior CU's only look at the xml schema relevant in the VersionOverridesV1_0 section?

Comment: For Exchange 2016 CUs, this is a temporary issue. Once all users upgrade to CU4, this issue will no longer exist.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN blog: Pinnable Taskpane in Outlook 2016](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2017/01/26/pinnable-taskpane-in-outlook-2016/) new VersionOverrides version 1.1 has to be added to an existing version 1.0. Your example manifest completely missing version 1.0 overrides. Please follow the example [command-demo-manifest.xml](https://github.com/jasonjoh/command-demo/blob/master/command-demo-manifest.xml) to make new pinnable feature work.

EDIT:
To clarify with VersionOverrides element, when implementing multiple versions, please refer to [VersionOverrides element: Implementing multiple versions](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/versionoverrides?product=outlook#implementing-multiple-versions)

Comment: Are you referring to the first line of the manifest?

The Version Overrides 1.1 section is within a Version overrides 1.0 section.

The weird part is that it works when we test the manifest on an Exchange 2016 server that is on CU4.

Answer (score 1):

Slava's answer is correct but could use a bit more explanation. The key line from the [documentation](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/versionoverrides?product=outlook) is:

> "The child VersionOverrides element does not inherit any values from the parent."

In your example schema you replicated the `<hosts>` element alone. In order to work properly, it must also replicate the `<requirements>` element from it's parent.

Comment: Is there any reason such a manifest (without the hosts element) would work on Exchange 2016 CU2+? We've been successful there.
Is there something to Exchange 2016 CU1 that makes this case special?

Also the requirements element is optional, hopefully this shouldn't be a blocker of being able to install the app.